# Find the Disk Volume containing OS Folder using C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, share

How can I find out which disk volume contains the `OS folder` in a remote machine.

My purpose is to create a folder in the same disk volume. I could create the folder using `CreateDirectory` in `Admin$`. But what to do to create the same in the parent folder of `Admin$` using `C++`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Amartel : I want to get the location in remote machine.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. I guess, you should look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation. I'm not a specialist in it however.